# Find all my caches_action paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in Rails to find out all the caches_action paths Rails have stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I ended up using ActionController::Base.cache_store and checked the cache directory manually. Let me know if there is a better answer.